To and from nodes in stream network using Whitebox Tools (in R)
I am experimenting with the WhiteboxTools via the WBT library in R. This is to design a scriptable and open-source workflow to extract stream networks from a digital elevation model (DEM).
From Archydro, I am used to getting a vectorized river network with topologic information. Specifically, each link in the river network would have a to_node and from_node id, i.e., information about where the link originates and ends (as a unique identifier, not coordinates). This information can then be used for all sorts of connectivity analyses.
Does anyone know if WhiteBox has similar functionality?
I can assign individual IDs to stream links (whitebox::wbt_stream_link_identifier) and extract those IDs into a vector river network (whitebox::wbt_raster_streams_to_vector), but that does not give me information about upstream and downstream nodes.

I known you have specifically asked about WBT but RivEX creates that information and write it back to the input vector dataset as a set of fields RivID, Fnode and Tnode. There is even a tool that can export the topological information into plain text file to allow it to be consumed by other software.

Hi @Hornbydd thanks for the suggestion and I did not know RivEX- so good to know for my reference. However I was specifically looking for an open source workflow not depending on paid software

I am still not sure if this is possible with native Whitebox tools.
However, when working with R there is an easy workaround.

delineate stream network as usual (condition DEM,flow direction,flow accumulation) using WhiteBox functions
define a network of unique stream identifiers with wbt_stream_link_identifier()
extract river network as vector with wbt_raster_streams_to_vector()
load resulting vector network back into R
use as_sfnetwork() from package sfnetworks to define network topology and open a slew of options for advanced network analysis

(step 2 is useful to get unique identifiers linking the network analysis back to other outputs of WhiteBox, e.g., drainage basins and such)
